# Gathering with tidyr from wide to long format by start of column name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
obs pre.data1   post.data1  pre.data2   post.data2  pre.data3   post.data3
1   0.40    0.12    0.61    0.15    0.58    0.06
2   0.21    0.05    0.18    0.49    0.35    0.24
3   0.48    0.85    0.00    0.62    0.96    0.37
4   0.66    0.29    0.88    0.56    0.13    0.72
5   0.43    0.23    0.80    0.78    0.05    0.90
6   0.86    0.04    0.25    0.34    0.99    0.79
7   0.57    0.86    0.20    0.34    0.11    0.34
8   0.13    0.39    0.24    0.51    0.79    0.63
9   0.87    0.57    0.00    0.55    0.86    0.72
```

I've attached an example of my dataset above.

I'm trying to convert from wide to long format with tidyr based off of the prefixes pre and post of each variable. Ideally I would like my data to be in the following format

```
obs key    data1    data2   data3
1   pre     0.50    0.26    0.12
1   post    0.18    0.50    0.42
2   pre     0.06    0.07    0.47
2   post    0.98    0.87    0.89
3   pre     0.34    0.55    0.72
3   post    0.26    0.99    0.71
4   pre     0.64    0.80    0.54
4   post    0.01    0.36    0.38
```

I'm fairly new to R but I know it uses the gather function, but I'm only familiar with gather with 2 columns as shown on many tutorial. Is there a simple way of doing the above? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

We can do this easily with `data.table` as the `melt` in `data.table` (to convert from 'wide' to 'long' format) can take multiple `patterns` for the `measure` columns.

```
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("data1$", "data2", "data3"), 
    value.name = c('data1', 'data2', 'data3'), variable.name = 'key')
dM[, key:= unique(sub("\\..*", "", names(df1)[-1]))[key]]
dM[order(obs)]
#    obs  key data1 data2 data3
# 1:   1  pre  0.40  0.61  0.58
# 2:   1 post  0.12  0.15  0.06
# 3:   2  pre  0.21  0.18  0.35
# 4:   2 post  0.05  0.49  0.24
# 5:   3  pre  0.48  0.00  0.96
# 6:   3 post  0.85  0.62  0.37
# 7:   4  pre  0.66  0.88  0.13
# 8:   4 post  0.29  0.56  0.72
# 9:   5  pre  0.43  0.80  0.05
#10:   5 post  0.23  0.78  0.90
#11:   6  pre  0.86  0.25  0.99
#12:   6 post  0.04  0.34  0.79
#13:   7  pre  0.57  0.20  0.11
#14:   7 post  0.86  0.34  0.34
#15:   8  pre  0.13  0.24  0.79
#16:   8 post  0.39  0.51  0.63
#17:   9  pre  0.87  0.00  0.86
#18:   9 post  0.57  0.55  0.72
```

---

Or using `tidyr`, we convert to 'long' format with `gather`, then `separate` the 'Var' column in to 'key' and "Var2' and `spread` it to 'wide' format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df1, Var, Val, -obs) %>% 
      separate(Var, into = c("key", "Var2")) %>% 
       mutate(key = factor(key, levels = c("pre", "post"))) %>%
      spread(Var2, Val)
#   obs  key data1 data2 data3
#1    1  pre  0.40  0.61  0.58
#2    1 post  0.12  0.15  0.06
#3    2  pre  0.21  0.18  0.35
#4    2 post  0.05  0.49  0.24
#5    3  pre  0.48  0.00  0.96
#6    3 post  0.85  0.62  0.37
#7    4  pre  0.66  0.88  0.13
#8    4 post  0.29  0.56  0.72
#9    5  pre  0.43  0.80  0.05
#10   5 post  0.23  0.78  0.90
#11   6  pre  0.86  0.25  0.99
#12   6 post  0.04  0.34  0.79
#13   7  pre  0.57  0.20  0.11
#14   7 post  0.86  0.34  0.34
#15   8  pre  0.13  0.24  0.79
#16   8 post  0.39  0.51  0.63
#17   9  pre  0.87  0.00  0.86
#18   9 post  0.57  0.55  0.72
```

---

This can be also done using `reshape` from `base R` (though, it may need some post-processing to make it tidy)

```
reshape(df1, idvar="obs", varying = list(2:3, 4:5, 6:7), direction="long")
```

Answer (score 3):

In `tidyr`:

```
# melt to long form
df %>% gather(var, val, -obs) %>% 
    # separate into key and test labels
    separate(var, c('key', 'var')) %>% 
    # spread to wide form
    spread(var, val) %>%
    # make it pretty so pre is before post for each obs
    arrange(obs, desc(key))

#    obs  key data1 data2 data3
# 1    1  pre  0.40  0.61  0.58
# 2    1 post  0.12  0.15  0.06
# 3    2  pre  0.21  0.18  0.35
# 4    2 post  0.05  0.49  0.24
# 5    3  pre  0.48  0.00  0.96
# 6    3 post  0.85  0.62  0.37
# 7    4  pre  0.66  0.88  0.13
# 8    4 post  0.29  0.56  0.72
# 9    5  pre  0.43  0.80  0.05
# 10   5 post  0.23  0.78  0.90
# 11   6  pre  0.86  0.25  0.99
# 12   6 post  0.04  0.34  0.79
# 13   7  pre  0.57  0.20  0.11
# 14   7 post  0.86  0.34  0.34
# 15   8  pre  0.13  0.24  0.79
# 16   8 post  0.39  0.51  0.63
# 17   9  pre  0.87  0.00  0.86
# 18   9 post  0.57  0.55  0.72
```